# Creating multiple matrices with a "for" loop

Tags: r, matrix

I am currently in a statistics class working on multivariate clustering and classification.  For our homework we are trying to use a 10 fold cross validation to test how accurate different classification methods are on a 6 variable data set with three classifications.  I was hoping I could get some help on creating a for loop (or something else which would be better that I don't know about) to create and run 10 classifications and validations so I don't have to repeat myself 10 times on everything....  Here is what I have.  It will run but the first two matrices only show the first variable.  Because of this, I have not been able to troubleshoot the other parts.

```
index<-sample(1:10,90,rep=TRUE)
table(index)
training=NULL
leave=NULL
Trfootball=NULL
football.pred=NULL
for(i in 1:10){
training[i]<-football[index!=i,]
leave[i]<-football[index==i,]
Trfootball[i]<-rpart(V1~., data=training[i], method="class")
football.pred[i]<- predict(Trfootball[i], leave[i], type="class")
table(Actual=leave[i]$"V1", classfied=football.pred[i])}
```

Removing the "[i]" and replacing them with 1:10 individually works right now....

Comment: what is football? Can you show what is it and what it contains?

Comment: I think you can create `Trfootball`, `leave`, `training`, `football.pred` etc as list i.e. `Trfootball <- vector('list', 10)` and then inside the `for` loop.  use `[[i]]`  (not tested without a reproducible example)

Comment: The original data football is a 7x90 matrix with categories 1-3 in the first column and 6 variables of observational data to fill up the rest.  Here is an example of what the football data looks like.

    set.seed(90)  
    v1=sample(1:3,90,rep=TRUE)  
    v2=sample(3:46,90,rep=TRUE)  
    v3=sample(7:20,90,rep=TRUE)  
    v4=sample(6:12,90,rep=TRUE)  
    v5=sample(5:15,90,rep=TRUE)  
    v6=sample(11:15,90,rep=TRUE)  
    v7=sample(1:18,90,rep=TRUE)  
    football=cbind(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies is the assignment of a `data.frame` or `matrix` to a vector that you initially set as `NULL` (`training` and `leave`). A way to think about it is, you are trying to squeeze in a whole matrix into an element that can only take a single number. That's why `R` has a problem with your code. You need to initialise `training` and `leave` to something that can handle your iterative agglomeration of values (the `R` object `list` as @akrun points out).

The following example should give you a feel for what is happening and what you can do to fix your problem:

```
a<-NULL # your set up at the moment
print(a) # NULL as expected
# your football data is either data.frame or matrix
# try assigning those objects to the first element of a:
a[1]<-data.frame(1:10,11:20) # no good
a[1]<-matrix(1:10,nrow=2) # no good either
print(a)

## create "a" upfront, instead of an empty object
# what you need: 
a<-vector(mode="list",length=10)
print(a) # empty list with 10 locations
## to assign and extract elements out of a list, use the "[[" double brackets
a[[1]]<-data.frame(1:10,11:20)
#access data.frame in "a"
a[1] ## no good
a[[1]] ## what you need to extract the first element of the list
## how does it look when you add an extra element?
a[[2]]<-matrix(1:10,nrow=2)
print(a)
```